# Add BOM in the beginning of a String

Tags: java, dataweave, mule-el

I have exposed a GET in an API which returns an application/csv back to the caller. NB: the resulting application/csv is just a string.  The caller wants the result to include a BOM.

This is how I set the contents of the returned application/csv with MEL:

> #[flowVars.csvFile]

I am trying to add the BOM with a simple concatenation, but it doesnt work.

How should I add the BOM in the beginning of a String?

If it cannot be done with MEL, is there a way with dataweave or java/groovy?

Comment: Hi @Aaron, the problem is that the file in the article you are pointing to is directly written to the file system while I return the resulting client back over HTTP call

Comment: Wouldn't the most upvoted answer still work for you? You must have an OutputStream somewhere on which you could `write('\ufeff')`, haven't you?

Comment: @Aaron you are right, this works when I test groovy only. However, it is Mule that changes the String and it strips the BOM when it gets returned to the customer.

Comment: Ah, I can't help you there, I don't know the first thing about Mule. Still, I'd expect a settings to disable such feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Postman do not show the BOM. Otherwise the linked solution works perfectly.